# Pulling and showing data from associate table in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build an API using Django Rest Framework. Which i am not familiar with. I want to know how I can pull data using references and associated tables. I have three models Users, Company and Reviews. I am storing and Auth_token in user table and I want to be able to pull reviews by a certain user by putting the auth token in the address bar.

my models are

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    auth_Token = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=uuid.uuid4)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user_name

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name

class Review(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

I am currently able to pull reviews using following apiview:

```
class ReviewView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        reviews = Review.objects.all()
        serializer = ReviewSerializer(reviews, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and the following serilaizer:

```
 class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Review
         fields = ('title','company', 'rating', 'summary','user')
```

Please ignore the indentations. However this results in me getting back the company id and user id only.  I basicaly want to know two things here.

First how do i pull data where auth token is passed as the url

```
url(r'^reviews/(?P<auth_Token>[\w-]+)/$', ReviewView.as_view()),
```

and second how do i display company name and user name instead of ids. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Note that one of Django's key advantages is its User model and user sessions, so you should not be creating your own User model unless you really know what you are doing. And django-rest-framework comes with support for authentication tokens so you should not reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

1. **How do I filter reviews based on the user's auth token?**

I will suggest using a `ReadOnlyModelViewSet`. It will greatly reduce your view code and allow for easy filtering. Most of the mundane and tiring code of handling requests, validating and so on has already been written in these viewsets and therefore, you can just focus on your business logic rather than server side details.

Instead of using an auth_Token in the URL param itself (eg. `reviews/XXX/`), I have placed it as a query param (eg. `reviews/?auth_Token=XXX`). The reason behind this is because the URL param itself should return a specific review resource but you need to return a list of filtered reviews mapped to one user.

```
 from rest_framework import viewsets

 class ReviewView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReviewSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This function is called whenever someone tries to retrieve reviews. 
        You do not need to worry about serialization or handling the response 
        as the viewset has set that up with your specified serializer_class
        """

        auth_Token = self.query_params.get("auth_Token", None)
        if auth_Token: # They provided an auth token so we need to filter.
            reviews = Review.objects.filter(user__auth_Token=auth_Token)
        else:
             reviews = Review.objects.all()
        return reviews
```

In your `urls`:

```
url(r'^reviews/$', ReviewView.as_view({"get":"list"})),
```

2. **How do I show the company name and user name in retrieved reviews and not show their ids?**

You need to use a `SlugRelatedField` (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield). This field allows you to replace the typical `id` with another attribute found in the associated table. Please see the new `ReviewSerializer` below:

```
class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    company = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field="company_name")

    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field="user_name")

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('title','company', 'rating', 'summary','user')
```

Comment: My bad i can see you need auth token as a url param. Give me one second to fix my answer.

Comment: Fixed - please see new answer

Comment: If you are simply retrieving a list of reviews, try ReviewView.as_view({"get":"list"}) in your urls.py. My comment was posted as an answer before for some reason. I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I might be doing this wrong but this did not work for me. First error I get is:
    get_queryset() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Now this might be totaly wrong but i removed request  from get_queryset(self). Then it gives me following error:

Cannot resolve keyword 'auth_Token' into field. Choices are: company, company_id, created_at, id, ip, rating, summary, title, updated_at, user, user_id

Comment: Yes sorry i left `request` in by accident. I have edited my answer. Typical speaking, `reviews/XXXAUTH_TOKEN/` should retrieve one specific review. But you need it to be retrieving reviews for a specific user. As such, I believe you should use query params (what I had originally posted) if you want to filter through a list of reviews. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the `urls.py` and your `ReviewView` to work with query params instead of url params.